# How to install phpsh on windows machine?

Tags: php, phpsh

I'm trying to install phpsh on my windows machine but i get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "setup.py" , line 8, in (module)
           from phpsh import __version__
       File "src/phpsh.py", line 1, in (module)
           ___init___.py
NameError: name ' ___init___ ' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

even if you install it, there isn't a module `readline` in windows, and that can only be found in Linux or Mac.

Solution:

1. Use a Virtual Machine running Ubuntu and install phpsh
2. Install Sublime Text go to Tools->Build System and paste

   ```
   {
     "cmd": ["path to php binary", "$file"]
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you kidding me?  Is it really required to run an entirely different operating system in order to run PHP interactively?  Seriously?  That's like using a sledgehammer to nail in a tack.